# Unable to ping sites outside my internal network (but able to browse to them without issue)

Tags: windows-7, cisco

I'm having an issue pinging sites that are outside my network. I'm able to ping sites inside the network and I can ping sites outside the network from a different connection so I know it's not an issue with my computer.

I'm still able to browse to websites and when I ping them, it will resolve the site's IPs, but it can't actually ping them.

Everything was working fine until some point yesterday. The only firewall in this office is a Cisco ASA 5505 and I didn't make any config changes on that before or after the issue appeared.

Does anybody know what could be going on?

I'm running Windows 7 Professional 32-bit.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ICMP is being blocked either outbound or inbound by your firewall.

Answer (score 1):

James is spot-on. ICMP is being blocked.

You say you didn't make any changes to your firewall - is it possible someone else did? Alternately are there upstream firewalls that could be filtering this traffic?

Or could the filtering be happening downstream, such as on your computer via Windows Firewall? If you've installed any updates recently one of them may have altered default behaviour or settings.

Comment: I suppose it could be the ISP, too, though I've never seen that happen.

Answer (score 1):

It was working then suddenly it stopped working...
There are issues with *Windows 7*, you should try from a Linux box inside your network.

Try also the `traceroute` command on Linux. Or the `tracert` Windows command that uses also `ICMP`. And see where it stops answering.